# Is the past tense of *Goes to* is *went*?

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect, past-simple, reported-speech

"According to police, the girl went for her daily tuition to prepare for the board examinations."

What is the meaning of above sentence?

A) Does it mean that girl had gone to tuition for preparation of examination?

If correct then why reporter has used simple past and not past perfect?

b) Or, Every day she goes to Tuition for preparation of her examination. I mean above sentence is the simple past tense of "She goes to Tuition every day for preparation of her exam".

c) Or anything else.

For reference please read below link.

http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/city/ajmer/Class-X-girl-abducted-abused-dumped-by-stalker/articleshow/55300695.cms

Comment: For your benefit, it is best practice on ELL to wait at least 24 hours before accepting an answer. This allows many more native speakers of English a chance to see and respond to your question. Also, once you accept an answer, you are less likely to receive more answers. See [Not so fast! (When should I accept my answer?)](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/not-so-fast-when-should-i-accept-my-answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a possible ambiguity with the simple past. It can refer to something done regularly in the past or to something that took place on a particular occasion in the past. However, with contextual clues, the ambiguity can be resolved. Here we have the word **daily**.  Thus, native speakers would understand the sentence to mean that on that day, as on most days, she had gone to her daily tuition.

The past perfect makes clear that we are referring to a particular occasion or event relative in time to another in the past.

P.S. In reported speech, there is often a backshift of tense, but it, too, like the past perfect, is not obligatory; in the presence of other contextual clues, it merely corroborates the fact that the speech is indirect; the backshift is not needed to establish that fact.

Comment: As always, if you're going to downvote, provide a reason.

Comment: -1 The presence of *daily* does not resolve the inherent ambiguity.

Comment: Of course it does. **daily** indicates that it was customary or regular activity. What ambiguity do you still perceive?  "We went to the beach when I was a kid".  "We went to the beach *each summer* when I was a kid".  In the first, without **each summer**, we don't know if it was a single occurrence or a customary thing. In the second, we know that it was a customary thing.

Comment: She went for her daily tuition **implies** that on a particular day she went there. If there was police involved, it is MOST likely, to be one particular time. And not: She used to go to her daily tuition at those times. "We went to the beach [in the summer] when I was a kid". Does not imply **each summer**. /We used to go to the beach, when I was kid/ does. Daily tuition can name an activity performed daily but use of the simple past implies it refers to that but on a **particular** day.

Comment: @Lambie: you have misunderstood what I wrote.  I was contrasting two sentences. 1) We went to the beach when I was a kid. and 2) We went to the beach each summer when I was a kid. Note the quotation marks around the sentences.

Comment: @TRomano I understand exactly what you are saying, believe me. It is you who do not understand what I am saying. The sentence cannot materially mean: We went to the beach every summer [not each] when I was a kid. That is based on not understanding that DAILY does not mean the verb implies: every summer. It does not.

Comment: @Lambie: You're trying my patience. What sentence are you referring to when you write "The sentence"?  And you're making up words I never wrote. And WTF does this sentence of yours mean "That is based on not understanding that DAILY does not mean the verb implies: every summer. "  What does "DAILY" have to do with "every summer"??  I was using a different time-phrase. I know that daily has nothing to do with summer.

Comment: @TRomano in your first comment, you talk about the first and the second. There is only **one sentence** and the first and second are only interpretations of it by the OP, which are incorrect. And in that single OP sentence, there is only one possible meaning.

Comment: @Lambie: re your "There is only one sentence..." In my first comment below my answer, I am referring to the two sentences *offered in the body of my comment*. As I said two comments ago, you misunderstood that comment.